# Inverse Function Thorem

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be smooth functions with $f(0)=0$ and f'$(0)\neq 0$. Consider the equation $f(x)=tg(x), t\in \mathbb R$.

Show that in a suitable small interval $|t|\leq \delta$, there is a unique continuous function $x(t)$ which solves the equation and satisfies $x(0)=0$.

Derive the first order Taylor expansion of $x(t)$ about $t=0$.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Implicit Function Theorem instead. You'll get a smooth such $x(t)$. Start with $F(x,t)= f(x)-tg(x)$ on a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.